# How can I deploy Camel application on JbossFuse server?

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

I`m trying to deploy camel application to jbossfuse server. It deployed but camel does not works.

I have simple apache camel application which creating "inbox" folder and after u add some file into this folder it will be copied in "outbox". When Im running application with mavens camel plugin it works fine "mvn camel:run".
But if I deploy bundle through redhatfuse directly it does not works.
my steps to deploy:

```
run fuse.bat;
install mvn:${path to local maven repository}
BundleID: 233
start 233
```

I can see my bundle started in "list" command but camel does not works. 
What can be the problem?
My applicationContext.xml which is under resources/META-INF/spring

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi" xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf-2.8.3.xsd">

    <camelContext id="camelId" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <camel:route>
            <camel:from uri="file:C:/inbox" />
            <camel:to uri="file:C:/outbox" />
        </camel:route>
    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

Comment: Can you look in the logs? Also what version of Fuse are you using? And what does your bundle contain, just that spring xml file? Also mind spring-dm (xml) is deprecated on OSGi and we recommend to use OSGi blueprint XML instead. Look at the examples from jboss fuse.

Comment: And you can use RH customer portal to get commercial assistance with this

Comment: @ClausIbsen Bundle contains camel project, but only this XML matters, yes.I will check, thanks.